# Creating personal list view programmatically with "Manage personal views" permissions only

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

In project, I'm currently working on, I have to create personal list view for given list (SharePoint 2007). Here is my code (*currList* is *SPList*):

```
System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection viewFields = currList.Views[BaseViewID].ViewFields.ToStringCollection();
SPView searchView = currList.Views.Add(SearchViewName, viewFields, query, 100, true, false, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPViewCollection.SPViewType.Html, true);
```

Everything's working fine when the user has permission to ADD elements to the list. Creating view for user, which has ALL permissions to the list except adding items gives "Access is denied" error. Adding view from SharePoint itself works.

I've found the same problem here:
http://us.generation-nt.com/security-issue-while-creating-personal-view-programmatically-help-86373652.html
so the problem isn't new.

//EDIT:
If I create personal view (having add items to list and manage personal views permissions) I can later modify this view (remove view fields from it, etc.) with manage personal views permnission only.
What's interesting is thatif I've created this personal vier earlier I can modify this view

Comment: Can you confirm - does the user who is running the code have permissions to create and manage personal views?

Comment: OK, that doesn't help then I guess... I have you tried putting the name (as a string) into the view name instead of using the 'BaseViewID' value for the view you want to generate your personal view from as I had an issue when testing using the BaseViewID but it worked fine if i used the views name?

Comment: I haven't tried that yet; I'll check that.

Comment: No result. It's a problem with adding view, not retrieving base view.

Comment: Hmmm... Can i ask what you are passing as the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem still exists in SharePoint 2010. Adding views with *Manage personal views* is not possible from code, but it's possible from UI. As a workaround in new project I've created JS script which:

1. loads *Create View* page to invisible frame
2. fills *View Name* field
3. selects "Create a Personal View" checkbox
4. clicks *OK* button
5. removes frame

I'm using jQuery to do this. Clicking button causes postback, so it must be handled:

```
createPersonalView = function (callback) {
    var url = siteCollectionUrl + '_layouts/ViewNew.aspx?List={' + listId + '}'
        + '&Source=' + window.location.href;

    $someDiv.append('<iframe class="view-creator" style="display:none;"></iframe>');

    $someDiv.find('iframe.view-creator').attr('src', url);
    $someDiv.find('iframe.view-creator').load(function () {
        var $iframe = $(this);
        $iframe.contents().find('#ViewName').attr('value', "My personal view");
        $iframe.contents().find('input#PersonalView0').attr('CHECKED', 'true');

        $iframe.unbind('load');
        $iframe.load(function () {
            $iframe.remove();
            callback(); //it's done! :D
        });

        $iframe.contents().find('#onetidSaveItemtop').click();
    });
};
```

It's enough to do this once. When you have view then it can be updated with *Manage personal views* permission.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that adding views from the UI works, you can try replicating what is happening there.

Using firebug, you can see what is going on, basically the ViewNew page submits to this url

```
http://server.local/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=65001&BaseViewID=1
    &Cmd=NewView&ContentTypeId=0x&IsThereAQuery=FALSE
    &List=%7BE30D413B-B7E9-47EB-9D69-BC1D3A76A3FD%7D&NewViewName=YourNewView
    &Personal=TRUE
```

But with a many more parameters.

If you really need this feature, you could try that.

Comment: Unfortunately this won't be easy - many parameters, getting session id (from cookies), etc.